# Add direct link to the sub sections of the stackexchange.com "activity" tab

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, network-profile, activity

In Meta Stack Exchange and other sites, if I want to navigate to any of the sub section of the activity tab, I can navigate to there by the direct link.

Such as for **comments** section [`<sitename>/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments) and for
**revisions** section [`<sitename>/users/current?tab=activity&sort=revisions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

But appending the [`&sort=comments`](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments), [`&sort=revisions`](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments) to the activity URL is not working in the stackexchange.com activity tab subsections.

So can the direct link to the subsection be implemented in the stackexchange.com too?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you only can go to:

https://stackexchange.com/users/activity/2855348?filter=comments

So add a `?filter=comments`, even though it looks ugly :-)

But I still agree with your point, this isn't the best yet.